# Why date is mismatch in JavaScript while conversion?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why date is mismatch in javascript .I am getting this millisecond **“-2208988800000”** .I converted this using moment  like this

```
moment(new Date(-2208988800000).toUTCString()).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

Which give output “01-Jan-1900"” (which is correct)

Now I try to get again same long value or millisecond

```
moment(new Date("01-Jan-1900")).format('x')
"-2209008070000"
```

Why is mismatch in value ?  "-2209008070000" and  "-2208988800000" is not same

Comment: I'm getting the right value, I'd imagine setting `new Date` adds the locale time (I'm in the UK hence mine is `Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT+0000 `)

Comment: I am in india ...but millisecond is different

Comment: Of course the millisecond is different; there's only a one in a thousand chance that it'd be the same. When you create the date without *specifying* the time-of-day value (including milliseconds), the current time according to your own computer is used.

Comment: hwo to get same long string ?

Comment: Well you could use a complete ISO-format time string, or use the Moment API that lets you provide the date string *and* a format string, which is preferred generally anyway.  (Also I may be wrong about `new Date()` using the current time; some platforms might do that but others might not; the trouble with `new Date()` is that platforms vary in what they accept.)

Answer (score 1):

`new Date("01-Jan-1900")` is not something that works in every browser. Firefox for example outputs `Invalid Date`. The `Date` constructor has lots of quirks, and it's exactly why you should use a library like Moment.js to parse date and time strings.

Refer to the [MDN documentation on `Date` and `new Date(dateString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for additional details.

Comment: @stijin how i will get same value using moment

Comment: You should post a new question (or preferably, look at the Moment.js documentation, which is very thorough) if you need help with that.

Comment: let take a example i am getting this "-2208988800000" from service .and show in UI "01-Jan-1900" now I want to send same long string

Comment: @user944513 Do you parse that as UTC or local time?

Comment: in UTC  ..I want if i get

Answer (score 0):

> I think you are losing hours while converting to DD-MMM-YYYY

```js
 console.log(moment(new Date(-2208988800000).toUTCString()).format('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'))

//output of above line is input to below.
console.log(moment.parseZone(new Date("31-Dec-1899 19:00:00")).format('x'))
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```